# Opera continually crashes every time I open it & is totally not usable

Tags: crash, opera

I'm using Windows XP and have Opera 30.0

Is that the latest version of Opera that works on XP???"

Opera has work very well for years, but suddenly now EVERY time I try to use it, it crashes after about 15 seconds. I reload it and then the same thing continues to happen over and over again.

I get a message that reads:

PAGE CRASHED  Unfortunately, something caused this page to quit. It might have been an extensions conflict or some other reason. Try reloading the page or navigate to another page to continue.

Going to another page does not work--same crash.

There is no error message # or option to even send a crash report.

Anyone figure out what is happening & how to fix it?

Many thanks.